# Null safe comparator with two compares in java

Tags: java, null, comparator

I have a list with rooms. Those rooms can be in usage by a person on a specific date or planned to be used in the future without having a specific date.
At first it went really well, but since we allow null values for the dates, I can't use this sorting method anymore.
The most important thing is, that it should first be sorted by person and then the dates should be listed. The null values should be on the bottom of each person listing. I tried a bit with nullFirst(), but didn't manage to write an error free code :D Most examples online only have one comparing, instead of two. (The person will never be null)

```
roomTOs.sort(Comparator
            .comparing(
                    personTO::getPersonName)
            .thenComparing(
                    personTO::getUsedDate));
```

Comment: In other words, you want to sort by name first. If the names are the same, arrange by date and dates which are null are treated as the "latest".

Comment: Exactly @Sweeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want something like this:

```
roomTOs.sort(Comparator
            .comparing(
                    personTO::getPersonName)
            .thenComparing(
                    personTO::getUsedDate, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            );
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid. This looks so easy and I just didn't think of just placing it in the "thenComparing"-Method. I tried so many complicated things, because my understanding of Comparator is so bad. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what if I want to do exactly the opposite? If dates are null or the same then sort by name.